# Why are my SQL queries failing?

Tags: php, sql

I tested the connection to the SQL and it is connecting properly. For some reason though, my queries are returning the `Error. BOOM!` message and they aren't working. Any idea what is going on?

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `members` 
(`id`,`fname`,`lname`,`password`,`email`,`vatid`,`transfer`, `link`, `ip`) 
SELECT `id`,`fname`,`lname`,`password`,`email`,`vatid`,`transfer`, `link`, `ip` 
FROM applicants WHERE id=$_GET[id]";

if ( !mysqli_query($connection,$query) ){
   // 
   //die (mysql_error());
   print("Error. BOOM!");
} else {
   //Or on success:
   print ("Thank you for your registration");
   //or you can do redirect to some page, like this:

  //header('location: /thanks.php');
}

$query = "DELETE * FROM applicants WHERE id=$_GET[id]";

if ( !mysqli_query($connection,$query) ){
   // 
   //die (mysql_error());
   print("Error. BOOM!");
} else {
   //Or on success:
   print ("Thank you for your registration");
   //or you can do redirect to some page, like this:

  //header('location: /thanks.php');
}
```

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the `mysqli_error()`? What did it tell you? You have comments for using `mysql_error()`, but that probably won't offer much information when you're using `mysqli_*` otherwise.

Comment: I hope $connection is initialized somewhere also

Comment: In the UK when an MP gets involved things go wrong!

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I have done this in comments to some of the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
DELETE * FROM applicants WHERE id=$_GET[id];
```

is not valid sql.  You have to lose the asterisk.

```
DELETE FROM applicants WHERE id=$_GET[id];
```

Among other things that make this difficult to debug, you are giving yourself the same output if either query fails.

Answer (score 1):

First the prerequisite, **Please switch to parameterized queries**. I'm not a PHP guy, but it looks to me like `$_GET[id]` is just a request parameter

```
INSERT INTO `members` (
    `id`
    ,`fname`
    ,`lname`
    ,`password`
    ,`email`
    ,`vatid`
    ,`transfer`
    ,`link`
    ,`ip`
    )
SELECT `id`
    ,`fname`
    ,`lname`
    ,`password`
    ,`email`
    ,`vatid`
    ,`transfer`
    ,`link`
    ,`ip`
FROM applicants
WHERE id = ?
```

My first guess is that id in members is a generated column; I don't know what RDBMS you're using but you may have to let the engine decide what the id for the new member is.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have a SQL injection issue. Always escape your variables before putting them, into your Query.

Use this to check for errors and get a better message on what is happening:

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
```

Also second query has a typo, Use this instead:

```
$query = "DELETE * FROM applicants WHERE id=$_GET['id']";
```

Comment: I'm not too worried about injections for what I am doing, but you are right that it is very bad to allow and easy to fix. I took your advice and used `mysqli_error()` to determine what the problem was. It says that `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM applicants WHERE id=1' at line 1` for `$query = "DELETE * FROM applicants WHERE id=$_GET[id]";`.

Comment: `$_GET[id]` should be `$_GET['id']`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this format for a delete query to determine the mistake:

```
<?php
$sql = " 
    DELETE FROM 
        applicants
    WHERE 
        id = ".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET[id])."
";

if(!$res = mysql_query($sql)) 
{ 
    trigger_error(mysql_error().'<br />In query: '.$sql); 
} 
elseif(mysql_affected_rows() == 0) 
{ 
    echo 'No records Deleted. <br />Query: '.$sql; 
} 
else 
{ 
    echo 'There are '.mysql_affected_rows().' records deleted.'; 
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using `mysqli_error()` to find the issue. It says that `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM applicants WHERE id=1' at line 1` for this line of code `$query = "DELETE * FROM applicants WHERE id=$_GET[id]";`.

Comment: Dont use the * in a delete query.

Answer (score -1):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$query = "INSERT INTO `members` (`id`,`fname`,`lname`,`password`,`email`,`vatid`,`transfer`, `link`, `ip`) SELECT `id`,`fname`,`lname`,`password`,`email`,`vatid`,`transfer`, `link`, `ip` FROM applicants WHERE id=".$_GET['id']."";

if ( !mysqli_query($connection,$query) ){
   // 
 //die (mysql_error());
 print("Error. BOOM!");
} else {
   //Or on success:
   print ("Thank you for your registration");
   //or you can do redirect to some page, like this:

  //header('location: /thanks.php');
}

$query = "DELETE FROM applicants WHERE id=".$_GET['id']."";

if ( !mysqli_query($connection,$query) ){
   // 
   //die (mysql_error());
   print("Error. BOOM!");
} else {
   //Or on success:
   print ("Thank you for your registration");
   //or you can do redirect to some page, like this:

  //header('location: /thanks.php');
}
```

or you can test your query in phpmyadmin in your database at the **sql** tab.

Or in your php-file put :

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: should be $_GET['id'] not $_GET[id]

Comment: That's right , I just forgot it. I answered fast, so I just maked a mistake